# Setting DataBinding in Runtime, causes me this Error "This causes two bindings in the collection to bind to the same property."

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding

I clear the binding before I try to add it again. This is the Error:

> This causes two bindings in the collection to bind to the same property.

```
this.txtHostname.DataBindings.Clear();
                this.txtPersonalnumber.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.bindingSourceComputer, "Person_ID", true));
```

Comment: You are refering different textboxes `txtHostname` vs `txtPersonalnumber`

Answer (score 1):

The error message is correct, because you are refering two different textboxes. You should either:

```
this.txtHostname.DataBindings.Clear();
this.txtHostname.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.bindingSourceComputer, "Person_ID", true));
```

or

```
this.txtPersonalnumber.DataBindings.Clear();
this.txtPersonalnumber.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.bindingSourceComputer, "Person_ID", true));
```

Probably the later one :-)

Comment: oh sorry, I did it like you said, I just copied the wrong one.
But now I have the Problem again, right here 
 
- I have a combobox and a textbox with the same value.

Comment: In case you have further different problems, you should check if the new problems is already answered and, if it is not, post a new question.

Comment: Clear will remove all bindings. Consider just removing the Text binding. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56719864/how-do-i-find-a-particular-binding-in-controlbindingcollection/56719914#56719914

Answer (score 0):

this.cbOwner.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("SelectedValue", this.bindingSourceComputer, "Person_ID", true));
                    this.txtPersonalnumber.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.bindingSourceComputer, "Person_ID", true));